# flask - send gzipped image

Tags: image, flask, gzip, sendfile

below you can find my old code (working) and my new code (not working). problem with the old code is that the images are 500 kb each and are provided while scrolling (lazy loading), so use up a lot of bandwith. The goal is to send the images gzipped, and have them unzip automatically by the browser, just like a gzipped webpage... how can I send a image compressed, so that when I load the url `/getLogImage/?fn=123.jpg` i see the actual file in the browser?

Old code:

```
@app.route('/getLogImage/')
def getLogImage():
    try:
        fileName = request.args.get('fn', None)
        return send_file("D:/images/" + fileName, mimetype='image/jpg')
    except Exception as err:
        return str(err)
```

New code:

```
@app.route('/getLogImage/')
def getLogImage():
    try:
        fileName = request.args.get('fn', None)

        # Read the original image file
        with open("D:/images/" + fileName, 'rb') as file:
            image_data = file.read()

        # Compress the image data using gzip
        compressed_image_data = gzip.compress(image_data, 9)

        return send_file(
            compressed_image_data,
            mimetype='image/jpeg',
            as_attachment=True,
            download_name='image.jpg.gz'
        )

    except Exception as err:
        return str(err)
```

Comment: Folks don't normally gzip JPEG/PNG or other already heavily-compressed images - have you tried gzipping on the command-line and comparing sizes?

Comment: nope, not tried.. but i just compared them now, after your sugestion and there is only a 0.6 kb size difference.. so i guess its useless.. thank you for your input.. please post it as answer so i can accept it..

Comment: I only added it as a comment intentionally and I can't bring myself to add it as an answer - so feel free to do so yourself. I'm glad it helped though.